# SSH connection not working in gitea

Tags: vps, docker-compose, gitea

I have setup gitea using docker-compose, External SSH port of my machine is 4444 which I set in sshd_config

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  gitea:
  postgres:
networks:
  gitea:
    external: false

services:
  server:
    image: gitea/gitea:latest
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: always
    networks:
      - gitea
    volumes:
      - gitea:/data
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "2222:22"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
      image: postgres:9.6
      restart: always
      env_file:
        - gittea_db.env
      networks:
        - gitea
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      volumes:
        - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Following is .env file

```
USER_UID=1002
USER_GID=1001
DB_TYPE=postgres
DB_HOST=postgres:5432
DB_NAME=gittea
DB_USER=gittea
DB_PASSWD=password12
INSTALL_LOCK=True
APP_NAME=myapp
RUN_MODE=prod
DOMAIN=source.smarticlelabs.com
ROOT_URL=https://source.smarticlelabs.com
SSH_LISTEN_PORT=22
SSH_PORT=2222
```

But when I try to clone a repo after adding my ssh key I receive this error

```
git clone ssh://git@51.15.245.237:2222/superadmin/testrepo.git
Cloning into 'testrepo'...
ssh: connect to host 51.15.245.237 port 2222: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: From your docker file your should try `git clone ssh://git@51.15.245.237:22/superadmin/testrepo.git` as the local 2222 port is redirected to 22. That's a totally different sshd daemon than the one running on your host.

Comment: Don't you have some kind of firewall on your machine that prevents you to connect to the port 2222 ? You may check with something like `iptables -L`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out this might actually be a **Firewall** issue.
To troubleshoot this you firstly should verify that your container is actually runing with `docker-compose ps`

```
# docker-compose ps
 Name                Command               State           Ports         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
server               [cmd ...]             Up              0.0.0.0:22->2222/tcp
```

Next you should check on your *Docker* Host that the Port is actually exposed with `netstat -lpn|grep -i 2222`:

```
# netstat -lpn|grep -i 2222
tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN      7216/docker-proxy-c
```

This should also match with the local *Docker* Host Firewall
with `iptables-save|grep -i 2222`:

```
# iptables-save|grep -i 2222
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.2/32 -d 172.18.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER ! -i br-0383ea873b82 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2:2222
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.2/32 ! -i br-0383ea873b82 -o br-0383ea873b82 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
```

When all these Checks are positive it might be an Issue with your **External Firewall** at your Internet IP `51.15.245.237`

You can check that with connecting from another Host on the same IntraNet as your *Docker* Host.